# Data trigger in static resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatrigger

I would like to make a template style, which I can use as a static resource, like this:

```
<TextBox 
  Style="{StaticResource CollapsingTextBox}"
  Text="{Binding SomeNullableValue}" />
```

Now as the name suggests, I would like the text box to collapse, when the binding value is `null`. Normally I would do this with a data trigger, like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeNullableValue}" Value="{x:null}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</DataTrigger>
```

But if I move the data trigger to a template style, which can be reused, then I it's no good to bind directly to the binding property (i.e. `SomeNullableValue`). Instead I need to bind the the binding of the template user (if that makes sense).

How do I achieve this kind of binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a Trigger with `Text` property:

```
<Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:null}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</Trigger>
```

Comment: Almost worked. Had to change it to `Value=""`. Not sure if it has to do with the Text property not being nullable (even if the underlying property is). Still, a nice and simple solution, thanks :-).

Comment: Text is string. string can be `null`. TextBox.Text can't become `null` via editing (deleting all symbols), and I'm surprised it isn't null, when binding property is. Interesting question if TextBlock has the same behavior. I would keep 2 triggers, just in case: for null and for empty string.

Comment: It might be related to the fact, that I am actually binding to a `decimal?` (nullable decimal). Still an interesting behavior though. Great idea with dual triggers.

Comment: Seems that the TextBox.Text property is never null. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18839129/1136211. Also the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.text?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) say that *getting this property returns a string copy of the contents of the text box*. So the `{x:Null}` Trigger is redundant. However, it doesn't hurt to have it, just in case.